# How to automatically run SSIS packages after doing batch updates in a DB2 database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, db2, mainframe

I don't know much about IBM DB2 databases. We have some SSIS packages which are presently run through a JAVA website by user once they get email notification of completion of Updates in a DB2 database.

Now they want to automate the process i.e automatically triggering the SSIS packages to run after updates in DB2.

The DB2 users say that they do the updates in DB2 though some batch. I am not sure what they mean by "batch". Can anyone who is good in DB2 explain about "batch" and how to connect to the SSIS server or the JAVA program from that batch.

It looks like it may need connecting from mainframe servers to windows server?

I don't know Java but I am good in C#/VB.Net/SQL. Any solution in C# is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A program on an IBM Mainframe which runs in "batch" is one that has no interaction with users.

Batch programs typically carry out the main workload of systems. Users enter "stuff" in the "online" system. When the online is finished, the Batch programs are run to process all the "stuff" against "existing stuff" and provide "new stuff" for the next online session.

The gap between the online sessions is often termed the "Batch Window". Online has to be "up" at a particular time, so all the Batch programs have to complete within the Batch Window.

That's the simplistic version of the "traditional" process. These days, there is some blurring, but a "batch" program runs without interaction.

There are many ways in which a batch program can let another system know that a particular state has been reached. These can involve the Scheduler product on the Mainframe, message queues, file transfers, email, etc.

The Mainframe "Production Control" people for your Mainframe site very probably have a preferred way for you to do this already in place and being used.

You need to locate them. Talk nicely to anyone you know who works with the Mainframe, call the Help Desk, ask your colleagues. Via whatever method, you need to find the people who already know what you should be doing *at your site*. And that isn't us.

In the unlikely event that no means already exists, they are still the people who will decide, and along with the equivalent people on the Windows side. It won't be something you are taking from the internet, or inventing yourself.

Comment: Yes, the batch program does sends the notification through email. And after that user has to manually click a button in a JAVA website in windows environment to run the SSIS packages.I was thinking that triggering the SSIS packages to run without user intervention from a different environment(mainframes) may not be an easy process. We might be needing an another program created in windows which gets the notification from mainframe batch program and then starts runnig the SSIS package. I am already talking about it to my mainframe colleagues but this is new for them also.

Comment: @DeepakMishra Well, something simple like FTPing a "trigger" file from the batch program to your Windows server, and then have the Windows scheduler look for it. However, you will need to check things like duplicate/multiple sends, no send, correct trigger, stuff like that.